# Transforms in physics?

Tags: fourier-transform

In my studies I have heard of two types of transformations in the physical science 1) the Fourier transform for diffraction and 2) the Legendre transform for thermodynamic potentials.

While mathematically I can see why they are different I am not really sure about what they mean and **why** they are different. To this end I am wondering what other types of transform there are and why we should distinguish?

Are these transformations different to Lorentz and coordinate transformations when discussing symmetry?

Comment: [Given this rather large list of mathematical transforms (via Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_transforms), this question is probably too broad as currently written.

Comment: @KyleKanos Wow! So it would appear. Rather than edit the question perhaps answers could be less detailed and just give a briefer overview?

Comment: That would still be too broad. If you are interested in what the transforms are (and some differences between the types), the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_%28function%29) is probably a good start.

Answer (score 1):

> Are these transformations different to Lorentz and coordinate transformations when discussing symmetry?

Yes and no. They have in common that we use them to look at the problem from another point of view.

When one study wave phenomena it is very common (if not automatic) to use the Fourier transform (and sometimes the Laplace transform). For example the Maxwell equations are often written directly in frequency domain, i.e. we applyied the Fourier transform on the equations (the advantage is that it transform the time derivative to a multiplication by the frequency).

The Lorentz and coordinate transform are somewhat different but the idea is the same: transposing the problem in a new space or domain where the calculations are easier and then if needed, going back in the initial space (the last point is maybe not necessary with coordinate transform).